# How to fix the disalignment of Show entries and Search of Datatables?

Tags: html, css, datatables, yii, datatables-1.10

I'm really bad at css or designing and I'm struggling to fix this.

Here is the outcome:

[image]

```js
<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script id=js-dispatcher src='scripts/scripts.js'></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var SubjTable = $("#SubjTable").DataTable({
        columnDefs: [ {
           targets:   0
        } ]
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You need to provide the full code or set up a codepen or something as your code is not reproducible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] for guidance on how to improve your question. There is no way for us to recreate your problem, based on the information you have provided. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre].